# String.split() method on object property set via API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, split, functional-programming

Hi I'm having a hard time understanding why `.split` isn't working on the string I am passing.
This is my string parser that returns the string as separate `<p>` tags

```js
const formatString = (str) => {
        return str.split('\n').map((line, index) =>
            <p key={index}>{line}</p>
        )
    }
```

I'm using an API that returns an object with a `description` property and a `meta` property.
Here's what the `description` value would display in the debugger:

```
description: "Level : Lv.3\nType : Creature\n\nA special monster that's only available on the ice 
island of Rien. One of the grown Murus featuring an unusually thick lips."
```

When I pass that property into my `formatString()` function, it doesn't split the string and return the separate `<p>` enclosed strings, rather its the original input that gets returned. I also set the input as a variable and passed that instead and received my expected output.

expected output:

```
Level : Lv.3
Type : Creature

A special monster that's only available on the ice island of Rien. One of the grown Murus featuring an 
unusually thick lips."
```

I've tried using a value declared both via `useRef()` and `useState()` and that seems to not matter. As far as immutability goes, `.split()` doesn't change the string, so I don't see why my function can't parse it.

Here is a link to the simulated problem on codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-maxwell-dhs4k?file=/src/App.js

Comment: The `.split` is doing its job correctly when I tested. Could you post a minimal complete example? Preferably on CodeSandbox

Comment: try changing your split method to `str.split('\\n')`

Comment: @Nishant I just included the link to the CodeSandbox in the question thread

Comment: I have fixed the code, there were more issues than just splitting "\n". See here: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-sun-gsn6g?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape `\` by using `\\`

```
const formatString = (str) => {
    return str.split('\\n').map((line, index) =>
        <p key={index}>{line}</p>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace all concurrences with a wildcard like {{n}}, and then do the split.

```
const formatString = (str) => {
         return str.replace(/\\n/gi,'{{n}}')
                   .split('{{n}}')
                   .map((line, index) => <p key={index}>{line}</p>); 
};
```